# Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type. / KnownKeys

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror

I am trying to enable strict in the application and I had interfaces that looked roughly like this:

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  archivedAt: Date | string;
  secondItem: SecondItem
}

interface SecondItem {
  name: string;
  content: string;
}
```

My problem was, that when creating a new object of type `Item` with extra values, the payload should be created. E.g.

```
data['someOtherKey'] = 'someOtherValue';

const item = new ItemCreatedPayload(data); // this should not throw, further description below
```

Instead I recieved the following error:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"someOtherKey"' can't be used to index type Item`

I managed to solve this by refactoring the interface:

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  archivedAt: Date | string;
  secondItem: SecondItem;
  [key: string]: unknown;
}
```

Here is my first question: **is there another way to achieve this?**

This works fine in tests, but errors in the app proper. That's how it's being used:

```
export class ItemCreatedPayload {
  constructor(
    public readonly item: Item,
  ) {
    const schema = Joi.object({ item: ItemCreatedSchema.required() });
    const { error } = schema.validate({ item }, { allowUnknown: true });

    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I'm emitting the event via nats microservice

```
this.events.emitItemCreatedEvent(new ItemCreatedPayload(item));
```

And I get this error: `Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'item'.`

I managed to get around this as well by using `KnownKeys` type:

```
type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K;
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U }
  ? U
  : never;
```

Like this:

```
export class ItemCreatedPayload {
  constructor(
    public readonly item: Pick<Item, KnownKeys<Item>>,
  ) {
    const schema = Joi.object({ item: ItemCreatedSchema.required() });
    const { error } = schema.validate({ item }, { allowUnknown: true });

    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

This solves the `Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Item'.` issue, but introduces a new one. Now in the event handler I am unable to access any item properties

```
  @EventPattern(EventName.ItemCreated)
  public async handleItemCreated(data: ItemCreatedPayload): Promise<void> {
    await this.items.findOrCreate({
      where: { id: data.item.id },
    });
  }
```

Error:
`Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Pick '.`

Now for the second and final question. **Does anyone know what the correct type here should be in order to get rid of `Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'item'.` and `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Pick '.` errors?** I am unable to fix both at the same time.

```
export class ItemCreatedPayload {
  constructor(
    public readonly item: ???????????,
  ) {
    const schema = Joi.object({ item: ItemCreatedSchema.required() });
    const { error } = schema.validate({ item }, { allowUnknown: true });

    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

I am aware that after typescript 4.3.0 the `KnownKeys` type is always `never` and I have tried every answer in this [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44143) without success.

It's hard to coherently represent this problem in the playground, but [here it is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIFcBGyDeAoZZYAEwC5kBnMKUAcwG48BfPPUSWRFAGTkwgA2AYTiRaAeygBPXASJlK1Oo0JwoCABbAAbhGIBBMOQAiolAB9FNELWSWQ6AQJXINWchkyMWbcNHhIyLz8ArjIAPThyAAO4hQUwJgCKGDiyPzIEAAekCDEeukyAEoQCJLEADxU1rQANMjoIADWIOIA7iAAfMhtWprItBAg0GYUyABEAJJ52ZTAtCCi6FAoMJLIYFLRKADk1XQ7RGMAtsDxdEQgG1s8fILjl8gCoBDkABwADHIk5Ps2LmpNDo9IYTGY7FYLvZHM45AI7sIzBJpORgoIRGJJFIXABtJoQKS-JQ2AC65EaLXaIHoESiYC0Y2iUHE2ygmyOlCwACtSmANmlNHAbBB6pBjtFKOIBOgwMBxFd6aIOa0+W1JE06MxWOx-FwggiACpQIUUeGy+WyQgCcQIODJIk1FxlPzgB3KOR4glu0nk5qtDo0yIbBkxZms9lnTmYHkIPmpZCC4WiiDiyXS80KjRKyMqnrqzU+HWcQJogRGk1muUgMb4K2G43Vyvyiio+sV0RVnEk7ysTbbfUhADKmhTcGQAF5LcgAPrTvtDODHCAAfnIO1LOxcP0h-zkiyX3oYcltmJRA-RSKxLmo7YzLeQ+igxqkFVL5cbHflnW8jDwCHh8TngIACi4DAOy+ByIQ0RYM8CAJisZgABTwiEGIQMiUiTMQq47rQACU5A4PIh4uIQ5EUZRqEXqeWEKH8R6UUxlGAlouhQNhpFQcxTGscCBhGMgpiQGRPFUQi6GYa2aGXtIolieR1Flg2pqftW0mCO+qkZl28kKcgTBTkxKxgMsVy1vp247DstTcTxSmSVinHINZtn6cgfHsc5rl2cxnkgoJwxtEJyH4W5+kObJhK4FZNkeeobEBeQQUhZASFha47hhLFBlMOFClKVpTbqcgOI4Natr2i5cXOrkgnWUwJL5ZRLAUSwPj-nAgGlkIiGQMQAAKcBSNacDEFOzrVOgsaSEh3EwUkwDwYhxDygIMhKRpoQAGRAUVakUPUQYUOIyyBOIMDBigZwUOgECHTE8KBPG0TwjIbTgRo1zbBQcj4UZyByO1rCdYBwG6OAFCDtA2hLSgFkLXBmSnGAPV9Xo4NDGASHRMNo0KGjEBmINePiGNhHINo4gkFOwN-gBYylhQJQnQI7EA5N1DTakUBzTxTI6OCK1rTIEAQ2A96Y5D0NQLDSDNRRAvaELROrSA61PAi96lqBsqbOF-04CwXVSCA8EIOjpZIaAMGCcRCZRc5DE0vurx4fQTAUwNzKnBQEAVMRm1AcOGijgZ3QWZR3Gc5rIQTh5bRwOBwZnAAdEpFCpxbRNpb5hA2zKWeO8QzX4aJ9Jp2LWOZym4GE8TUvYyl9f9UNI1k8QKEIvhZe0o9eoffS333ZcZTih2mDAM8sr3awFEmWZYRKQZHljEK2JA1q9NdYzCKN88VBDNAYRBvSKC2n7HLxlmugeQgSCAfGZ8uZFtGHKAV3IMQohjuI0a8sGbMYwLqfxAS3PQbd8bHmbFzGavNfJKxVmNEWmVMD3k8LrcCUgFahkFpAZAwt1YbQkrJYA90tqOWkJg-WCCaDK3wYQjWGctrUKkH9XAPhFawSWqvU28Esx5GSOAzu38wBwAoejEm7dybkG9uIX2-sqYkAjtHGBpU3CYBJPHOAidk4V0zhozOMBQDEAAPJQF6jnCASFI7kV6NAN2xFtyiLgOnBEbiZK0VTho1ONM8rcU9r+CiMccSvwwliLRk4dFJzjAyDxNFwk0HuqnYxeRzGWOQrYwg9iVhERIl-H+8SBBFMoVIXxJdUHOR8X45qgS57kWiXouJGcUkmPSejGxvkcmOPyS4op5T6hhMws5IZWJykGVqWXTePhwgACpWB2g4IsWUt9WYyirD0Lq-IEJWOHqvZAawnDtEBvOZAABpf0IAzkEgoBUA03RJwWRxGcx4+IpAgINGSPCmQchDGIGMF5y5kDDHZsldAxx+BQB+bkf55zkBApBcfcgZzvDQr+TWUq05XkEg+V80AMBj4AFUDJyCBYSuQyUq5QF-EKca6BL7J2ePicgrBsixDZAmBmQEMmt1JmNCaMCoDc1mvNbhy1VYoKDgNJaTRXwImQLtN8KlioPQuVSa5UhbmlgVXtZVB1OidANgDOmvQlpfSZOIYg00R7PzZbyAop0wBj2ulcFpKxWbs0wDKHZoxMhPkkGMD+SlU5V3AAAWgPrkY+VAOw2EAXycYcjwwyB2KM6QhxVoj1zNkM4fILSnJ2NKhATQXLjDwLM8IQA)

Anyway, thanks for your time. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: what about trying to make Item extending Record<string, any>. havent tried but might fix the index sigbature issue

Comment: @Jerome Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this does not solve the issue and I would prefer not to use `any`

Comment: can you create a complete example in codesandbox or any.other online IDE, because some info are missing in your code to get full context. BTW using Record<string, any> is not a bad practice in TS

Comment: @Jerome Could you elaborate why `Record<string, any>` is not a bad practice in strict mode?

Comment: Here is the sandbox tinyurl.com/2p8cu5yp